# L'usage du mot « quinquin » est-il répandu ailleurs que dans la région Lilloise ?

Tags: vocabulaire, régionalismes

Je sais que « [quinquin](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinquin) » signifie petit enfant et je connais son étymologie.

Cependant ce mot appartient-il au français régional de Lille ou son usage est-il répandu partout dans la France voire dans la Francophonie ?

Comment: A ma connaissance, son usage est très limité au nord de la France, et sa compréhension peut être un peu plus étendue, notament aux zones frontalières belges. Je n’en ferai pas une réponse car je n’ai aucune référence autre que mon expérience personnelle. Ayant de la famille habitant cette zone frontalière, j’ai été habitué à leur dialecte si bien que je n’ai pas trop de souci à comprendre le chti sans pour autant être à même de le parler, mais habitant moi-même plus au centre de la Belgique, je sais que mes amis y sont beaucoup plus hermétiques...

Comment: On le trouvais à Paris il y a quarante années de cela dans le nom d'une brasserie à côté de la gare du Nord; c'était « Le Petit Quinquin » ou peut être « Le P'tit Quinquin », je ne me souviens plus.

Comment: Le p'tit quinquin est aussi un bonbon lillois : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%27tit_Quinquin_(bonbon)

Comment: @LPH > Oui mais le bonbon s'appelle ainsi justement à cause de la berceuse...

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est expliqué en détail à la page qui correspond au lien  : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%27tit_Quinquin_(bonbon)

Comment: Étrangement j'ai pensé en reconnaître le son mais pas la graphie. Au pluriel avec le possessif et l'adjectif petit : _mes ti-quinquins_ (à un groupe d'enfants). Je pourrais dire ça, mais j'aurais vu ça comme une déformation de _coquin_, par antiphrase uniquement (parce que le sens à connotation négative n'est jamais employé dans mon groupe, au Qc). Merci !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour ce qui est de la francophonie, ce mot ne s'est pas rendu au Québec!